# Password history to prevent user to keep same passwords again and again

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, bcrypt

I am developing an application in PHP Laravel. It uses bcrypt encryption to store passwords. I want to keep the history of hashes whenever the user changes the password. By doing this I want to stop user entering the previous passwords in some scenarios. Is it safe to keep the history of hashes?

I am using built in functions. I do not know much about this encryption. According to my observation, if a user changes his password and keep the same as a previous one, the hash values come different. How can I stop him to keep the same password from the previous history? Is it possible while using bcrypt encryption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's totally safe. You can compare the new password with your older hashes using `Hash::check()`. For example like this (`$hashes` being an array of old hashes)

```
$newPassword = 'secret';
foreach($hashes as $hash){
    if(Hash::check($newPassword, $hash)){
        exit('Sorry can\'t use the same password twice');
    }
}
```